# Custom Select in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

is there a way to implement this kind of Select Component with Material UI?

I know there's grouping option in their Select Component, but am not sure if possible to create this in a way that each group is opened or close by clicking on the group name

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This looks similar to the MUI [Tree View](https://mui.com/x/react-tree-view/#gmail-clone).

Comment: @kofeigen forgot to thank you! that really helped me!